# How to display time only

Tags: oracle, time, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

[image]Can anyone help me how can I change the output of `Time_done` to a time only (example: 5:00AM)? If I add `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS')` on `SYSDATE`, I got an error message

> ORA-01843: not a valid month.

Below are my codes and screen capture of `EVENTLOGS` table

```
   CREATE TABLE EVENTLOGS(
        Eventlog_id   Number(3,0)   NOT NULL,
        User_name     Varchar2(20),
        Date_done     Date,
        Time_done     Timestamp,
        Action_done   Varchar2(50),
    CONSTRAINT PK_EVENTLOGS PRIMARY KEY (Eventlog_id));

/*  TRIGGER CREATION  */
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SUPERHEROES_AUDIT
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON SUPERHEROES
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
  V_LOGID NUMBER;
  V_USER  VARCHAR(30);
  V_DATE  DATE;

BEGIN
  SELECT EVENTLOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, USER INTO V_LOGID, V_USER FROM DUAL;
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVENTLOGS(Eventlog_id, User_name, Date_done, Time_done, Action_done)
    VALUES (V_LOGID, V_USER, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, 'INSERT');
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVENTLOGS(Eventlog_id, User_name, Date_done, Action_done)
    VALUES (V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, 'DELETE');
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVENTLOGS(Eventlog_id, User_name, Date_done, Action_done)
    VALUES (V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, 'UPDATE');
  END IF;
END;
/

[![INSERT INTO 
EMPLOYEE_T (EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress, EmployeeCity, EmployeeState, EmployeeZip, EmployeeBirthDate, EmployeeDateHired, EmployeeSupervisor)
VALUES (2, 'JACKIE', 'AFRICA', 'kenya', 'NO', 11285, TO_DATE('13-OCT-1950', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('27-JUN-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 455789);][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have posted an incomplete `TRIGGER` code with too many errors.

If you are inserting data into a `TIMESTAMP` column, you need to insert a compatible record. Inserting only time portion is not useful as you cannot do direct `date` arithmetic / comparison operations which may be required on the column. I have used `SYSTIMESTAMP` function here to insert current system `TIMESTAMP`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SUPERHEROES_AUDIT
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON SUPERHEROES
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
  V_LOGID NUMBER;
  V_USER  VARCHAR(30);
  V_DATE  DATE;

BEGIN
  SELECT EVENTLOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, USER, SYSDATE INTO V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE FROM DUAL;
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVENTLOGS(Eventlog_id, User_name, Date_done, Time_done,Action_done)
    VALUES (V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE, SYSTIMESTAMP, 'INSERT');
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVENTLOGS(Eventlog_id, User_name, Date_done,Time_done, Action_done)
    VALUES (V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE, SYSTIMESTAMP, 'DELETE');
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVENTLOGS(Eventlog_id, User_name, Date_done,Time_done, Action_done)
    VALUES (V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE, SYSTIMESTAMP, 'UPDATE');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Here is the sample data

```
select * FROM EVENTLOGS;


EVENTLOG_ID USER_NAME      DATE_DONE TIME_DONE                       ACTION_DONE 
----------- -------------- --------- ------------------------------- ------------
          1 SLDDEVELOPER   13-OCT-17 13-OCT-17 04.58.07.237343000 AM INSERT
```

If you need only time portion and not the `DATE` portion in your `time_done` column, then it should be a `VARCHAR2` column and you can use `TO_CHAR` while inserting in this case as you were attempting to do.

```
INSERT INTO EVENTLOGS(Eventlog_id, User_name, Date_done, Time_done,Action_done)
    VALUES (V_LOGID, V_USER, V_DATE, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI:SS'), 'INSERT');
```

Comment: Thank you again Kaushik!